# Выводится белый экран

Tags: laravel

Пытался сделать для начала простой вывод билетов, но появляется белый экран.

Сама форма:

```
<form id="searchh" action="{{ url('/search') }}" method="get">
        <p id="bilet">Поиск билетов</p>
        <div id="search1">
            <input list="search" type="search" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Откуда">
            <input type="search" name="kuda" id="city" placeholder="Куда">
            <input type="date" name="date">
            <button type="submit">Найти</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{ '$search' }}">
        </div>
```

Маршрут:

```
Route::get('/search/', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```

Контроллер:

```
public function search(Request $request){
$search = $request->input('search');
$posts = DB::table('cities')
->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
->get();
return view('search', compact('posts'));
}
```

Страница вывода:

```
@if (isset($cities))
    <table class="table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if($posts->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="post-List">
        <p>{{ $post-name }}</p>
        @endForeach
        @else
        <div>
            <h2>No posts Found</h2>
        </div>
        @endif
    </tbody>
    </table>
    @endif
```

Comment: `@if (isset($cities))...@endif` – что у Вас эта переменная делает и откуда берется?